# Multiplying in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm an Angular.js noob and I want to multiply two values get that sum of those values and then multiply the sum buy another value.

I want to input a value:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="averageSalary">
```

then get that result, then be able to enter another value:

```
<input class="input input-sm" type="text" ng-model="benefitsAt">
```

get the the sum of those to values and multiply that by:

```
<input class=" input input-sm" type="text" ng-model="occupancy">
```

I hope this helps, I tried to explain it the best that I could

Comment: You'll probably want `ng-change` directives on your inputs and a function in the controller to update scope values accordingly. As it is, your question is incomplete and will likely be closed. You should show your controller effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML ...

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="averageSalary">
<input class="input input-sm" type="text" ng-model="benefitsAt">
<input class=" input input-sm" type="text" ng-model="occupancy">
</form>
<span ng-bind="getMySum()"></span>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER ...

```
angular.module("myapp").controller('MyController', ['$scope',    function($scope) {
  $scope.getMySum = function() {
    return $scope.averageSalary * $scope.benefitsAt * $scope.occupancy;
  };
}]);
```

I havent tested this code - and I would use the Controller As sytax - but this seems pretty much what you want

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add something that outputs the display:

```
 <span>{{(averageSalary + benefitsAt) * occupancy}}</span>
```

You can or the result with zero to eliminate displaying null when the user hasn't entered anything:

```
<span>{{(averageSalary + benefitsAt) * occupancy || 0}}</span>
```

Comment: careful .. `(averageSalary + benefitsAt)` will concatenate  string values

Answer (score 0):

This code below should work and run for you.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.averageSalary =  55000;
    $scope.benefitsAt = .02;   
    
    $scope.$watch('averageSalary + benefitsAt', function() {
    $scope.occupancy = $scope.averageSalary * $scope.benefitsAt;
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  Average Salary
  <input type="text" ng-model="averageSalary"><br/>
  Benefits
  <input class="input input-sm" type="text" ng-model="benefitsAt"><br/>
  Occupancy
  <input class=" input input-sm" type="text" ng-model="occupancy"><br/>
</div>
```